# Calling method Design in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have one interface named `HasDescription`

```
public interface HasDescription {

    String getDescription();

    void setDescription(String description);
}
```

It has getter and setter method declarations.

I have another abstract class called `ResidentialProperty` that implements this interface.

```
public abstract class ResidentialProperty
        extends AbstractProperty
        implements HasDescription {
    .....
    private String description;

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

I have another class called `Flat`. In this class, i have delegated one `descriptionSupport`instance. My thought is that, using this instance, i want to call `ResidentialProperty`'s getter and setter method. I am coding this DescriptionSupport. Please assist me how i can do this?

```
public class Flat
extends ResidentialProperty {
 private final DescriptionSupport descriptionSupport = new DescriptionSupport();
 @Override
 public String getDescription() {
  return descriptionSupport.getDescription(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void setDescription(String description) {
  descriptionSupport.setDescription(this, description);
 }
}



public class DescriptionSupport {
 public < T extends HasDescription > String getDescription(T property) {
  //i want to call ResidentialProperty's getDescription method

 }

 public < T extends HasDescription > void setDescription(T property, String description) {
  //i want to call ResidentialProperty's setDescription method
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DescriptionSupport` helper class isn't needed. The `Flat` is subtype of `ResidentialProperty` - it inherits the implementation of setters and getters from its parent so you don't need to override them again.

If you still need to override the two methods, you can call their implementation from parent class using `super`, for example `super.setDescription(description)`.

Comment: I have taken this helper class to read description of any model. Let say, i have another model called House. Using this helper class i can read description of it.

Comment: If House also implements HasDescription interface, you can always read its description directly. Just work with variables of type HasDescription.

Comment: @Subhabrata Mondal: there’s still no explanation what purpose that helper class should fulfill. All you say you want to do, is already possible without that helper class.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `DescriptionSupport`, I propose some modification:

```
public class Flat extends ResidentialProperty {
    private final DescriptionSupport descriptionSupport = new DescriptionSupport();
    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return descriptionSupport.getDescription(super::getDescription);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        descriptionSupport.setDescription(super::setDescription, description);
    }
}

public class DescriptionSupport {
    public String getDescription(Supplier<String> s) {
        return s.get();

    }

    public void setDescription(Consumer<String> c, String description) {
        c.accept(description);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the added value of it? It tries to reimplement standard Java behaviour by custom constructs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what You're trying to do, but You could do something like this:

```
public class Flat
        extends ResidentialProperty {

    private final DescriptionSupport descriptionSupport = new DescriptionSupport();
    private final HasDescription superDesc = new HasDescription() {
        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return getSuperDescription();
        }

        @Override
        public void setDescription(String description) {
            setSuperDescription(description);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return descriptionSupport.getDescription(superDesc);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        descriptionSupport.setDescription(superDesc, description);
    }

    private String getSuperDescription() {
        return super.getDescription();
    }

    private void setSuperDescription(String description) {
        super.setDescription(description);
    }
}

public class DescriptionSupport {
    public < T extends HasDescription> String getDescription(T property) {
        return property.getDescription();
    }

    public < T extends HasDescription> void setDescription(T property, String description) {
        property.setDescription(description);
    }
}
```